# RabbitMQ - is it possible to consume messages through http POST

Tags: http, rabbitmq, http-post

I am using RabbitMQ as message broker. I want the messages from the queue to the consumer are sent by the Http POST method.
What I want is that when a message (body of the post formatted in JSON) is ready in the queue, it is sent to the consumer through HTPP post instead of AMQP.
Are there any plugins or something else?

I searched, but I only found HTTP API to publish a message, to manage the queues and to send GET req to the queues (but I do not want to do this).
Thanks